Generative models - valid distribution requirement
In "Deep learning" by Bishop there is a requirement for generative models that looks wrong to me

(Equation 14.49, page 452, online at https://www.bishopbook.com/ )
I think it should only require p(x|w) to integrate to 1 over x. Is there an error in the book or what am I missing?
My justification for doubting the equation: if you consider a uniform distribution p(x) over [0, 2], the equation doesn’t hold even if p(x|w) matches p(x).

Yes, knowing Bishop's interests, I suspect he meant p(X|W)p(W).

Unless I missed something it looks OK to me. Each $p()$ must integrate to 1 by definition. So $\int p(x|w)p(w); dx = 1$ provides that the joint distribution $p(x,w)$ is properly normalised over $x$ and $w$. Now, $\int p(x|w); dx = 1$, but the prior $p(w)$ must also be normalised. In your example, uniform $p(x)$ over $[0, 2]$ fails because $p(w)$ may assign weight to $w$ values where $p(x|w)$ predicts $x$ outside $[0, 2]$. This mismatch causes $p(x)$ (derived by marginalising $p(x|w)p(w)$ over $w$) to fail normalisation. Alignment of $p(x|w)$ and $p(w)$ ensures a valid probability model.

@RobertLong I'm not sure I get it - the "counter example" with uniform distribution over [0, 2] assumed that p(x | w) = p(x), i.e. the generative model gives the correct distribution independent of any parameters.

@RobertLong Regarding the general considerations, note that the book doesn't introduce a prior. If we consider a prior, note that w is fixed in the integral p(x|w)p(w) dx - I don't think it needs to integrate to 1, but rather to p(w)

Regarding your first comment, $p(x|w) = p(x)$ implies that $x$ is independent of $w$, which contradicts the role of $w$ in generative models. For $p(x) = U[0,2]$, $p(w)$ assigns weight to $w$-values that cause $p(x|w)$ to predict $x$ outside its support.
$$$$
Regarding your second comment, if $w$ is fixed, $p(w)$ places 100% probability on a single value of $w$, and $\int p(x|w)p(w) dx$ simply reproduces $p(w)$. However, if $w$ is a random variable with its own distribution, $\int p(x|w)p(w) dx = 1$ ensures that the joint distribution $p(x, w)$ is properly normalised over both $x$ and $w$.

BTW ,still not 100% on this TBH. I ought to read the book or at least Ch14.

If it's not incorrect it's at least confusing, so I wrote an email to the authors about it. Thanks you for your comments, even if I'm wrong at least I know that it's unclear to others as well and worth writing the email

@Bartosz No worries - it's an interesting problem to me and I would like to help if I can. I agree that it's confusing and my next piece of advice was to contact the author. Please do come back here if/when you get a response. It is completely OK to answer you own question (actually it is encouraged), so don't keep it to yourself please :). If you don't get a (useful) response please also come back here, as I would like to follow up
$$$$
My other advice is to re-post on stats.se. There you will find many, many more Statistics-focussed data scientists (whereas here most are CompSci-focussed).

@RobertLong I asked on CrossValidated SE https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/659069/generative-models-valid-distribution-requirement

Ahh. Thanks for letting me know and I’m very glad that it’s been resolved!

I got this wrong due to a combination of over-reliance on the source, failure to apply first-principles reasoning, and overcomplicating the interpretation. The correct explanation is simpler:: conditional probabilities like $p(x|w)$ must normalise over $x$, and the equation in question incorrectly extends this normalisation to the joint distribution. Sorry for leading you astray!

No worries, thanks for joining me in this ;)
